# Join two data sets by year in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two datasets which looks like:

```
# 2013_data.tsv
year    state   age
2013    CA  22,5
2013    OH  19,3
2013    IL  45,5
2013    TX  33

# 2012_data.tsv
year    state   age
2012    CA  23
2012    OH  21,5
2012    CA  44,3
2012    TX  34,4
```

I want to use `year` as a pager on the Tableau map.

How can I join this separate data sources?

Comment: That's a general software question so it's off topic for stackoverflow

Comment: This is a pretty specific question and there are quite a lot of [tableau] questions on SO. I do not think this one is too different from the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could blend on year, but if the year is always different in each data source then the blend will not match on anything and you will get no results.

I am guessing that each data source (tsv file) has the same format (same number of columns and column names). In that case you can extract each data source with tableau desktop and then add the data from each source to get a master extract. (you are basically appending the data extracts):

[image]

and you will get all the data in one extract:

[image]

from here it is simple to combine the years in one visualization.

Also, since this is SO, I will point out that you can do this programatically with the extract API (see https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/extract-api-introduction).

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach in this case is to put all the data into one table before using tableau. (It looks like what you really want is a union instead of a join)

Another approach is to put two tables in the same database, or two tabs on the same spreadsheet,and use custom SQL to union all them together. Or you can append multiple tables into a single Tableau extract as emh described.

If you are conceptually joining tables instead of unioning them, you could also use data blending.